# iOS Swift Can't identify error on run-time

Tags: swift, xcode, ios10

I'm having the weirdest error in Xcode while I'm running app on my device

It shows me this error:-

[image]

The error is:

> ```
> thread 1 exc_breakpoint (code=1, subcode = 0x1003a91fc)
> ```

Can y show me how to identify the error and what is the error?

Update: why this cause error??: [image: error]

Comment: Can you should the code that's at fault? `ViewController.numberOfItems(in: iCarousel`

Comment: I've just updated it, can you have a look again?

Comment: How is `sourceSegment` declared?

Comment: `code`@IBOutlet weak var sourceSegment: UISegmentedControl!`code`
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `sourceSegment` could be `nil` when you're checking the `selectedSegmentIndex`

To check if that's the case, try declaring it as

```
@IBOutlet weak var sourceSegment: UISegmentedControl?
```

instead.

My guess is somehow you're refreshing `iCarousel` before the view has loaded

Comment: Wow thanks. I do reload iCarousel after viewDidLoad(). But I guess that's not the problem

Comment: nils where I don't expect them is pretty much always the first place I look when debugging a Swift crash!

Comment: Looking at the stack, it seems that setting the dataSource on iCarousel forces a reload. I guess you're currently setting it before `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Thank you very much, you save my day

Answer (score 0):

Just click on `ViewController.numberOfItems(...` to see the line of code where an actual error occurred.

[image]

Comment: Can you check the post again, I've updated my question

Comment: @QuangDinhLuong without seeing your code I can only guess the segmentedControl instance was not properly initialized

Comment: What should I do?